# c# how to suppress "Unsupported 16-Bit Application" window popup in cmd.exe process

Tags: c#, cmd

**Short explanation:**

Starting a cmd.exe process from C# with an improper exe or com file as parameter opens an "*Unsupported 16-Bit Application*" window. 
Any idea how to detect / suppress this window and report an error to the caller?

**Longer explanation:**

In porting our server application from VMS to .NET I wrote a VMS/DCL command interpreter as we need to support DCL command scripts and we are not allowed to touch the business layer which supports DCL scripts. 
The DCL interpreter now also needs to call native programs and *cmd.exe* scipts.

For this, my DCL interpreter supports a "DCL" command which starts a *cmd.exe* process in a hidden window, redirects the input/output and/or passes a DCL parameter as script to *cmd.exe*.
Now, when a bad script file get's passed (ex. a DCL command file with a ".COM" extension), *cmd.exe* tries to start the file/program and launches a modal "*Unsupported 16-Bit Application*" window and this regardless of WindowStyle and CreateNoWindow.

As this runs on the server, I need to close/suppress the window and report an error back to my DCL.

**My solution:**

The only solution I could find till now was to check the MainWindowTitle of the launched process for "*Unsupported 16-Bit Application*", kill the process and report an error back to DCL.

But unfortunately as this runs in a separat process and DCL not necessarely needs to wait for the process to end, it's not defined at which point the title shows up and the check may be too early and fail.

Any ideas?

Comment: One way would be to check the file signature of the application beforehand or via [`getbinarytype`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getbinarytype). Finding the assemblies in the script might be a bit tiresome however.

Comment: Your I/O (standard input and standard output ) to cmd.exe is a stream.  So make sure the stream is set to UTF8.  Then you can take the byte[] array from the stream and use Encoding.Unicode to get your 16 bit data.

Comment: In fact, **getbinarytype** this is an idea to at least prevent a certain kind of errors. I could parse for .com and .exe and verify it's a binary before handing it over to cmd.exe. thanx!

Comment: To jdweng: sorry, you are not getting the question. It's not an encoding problem.

Comment: To  Manfred Radlwimmer: hm, I tried the following for the passed commands: evaluate the file path (I had to search for matching files in the PATH environmentVariable and the workingDir) and feed the result to GetBinaryType. GetBinaryType returned true and SCS_DOS_BINARY as file type. Kind of unexpected :)

Comment: I think you need to pinvoke [SetErrorMode()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetErrorMode.html), passing 2.  The child process inherits it.

Comment: To Hans Passant: unfortunaltly it seems like this does not help. I can't say yet if cmd.exe does not inherit the mode or if "Unsupported 16-Bit Application" is not honoring the mode.

Comment: It seems like , "Unsupported 16-Bit Application" is not handled via Windows Error Reporting and so SetErrorMode is no help. The only solution I found so far is to parse all input sent to the process (via parameter or command input), try to identify calls to binaries, try to find the path of the to be called binary and see if GetBinaryType reports a type supported by the running system. As this error prone, also periodically check for the main window title.

Comment: I was wrong in several cases (ex. WER is really in charge) and I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

[SetErrorMode](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetErrorMode.html) is infact the solution and it's even a documented errorMode.

The following line of code disables the message box:

```
var oldMode = SetErrorMode(ErrorModes.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
```

The following line will set it back to the original value:

```
SetErrorMode(oldMode );
```

Comment: Well, don't do *that*.  At least use GetErrorMode() so you don't screw up your own process too much.  And do try different bit values, you won't have check all 32 of them.

Comment: Well, I do call GetErrorMode but I just haven't found the bit I have to set. But with setting all 32 bits I could at least see WER is involvedand it's one of the 32 bits. In fact, as it's undocumented, every bit could have a potential bad impact.

Comment: Shame on me, it's a documented error! I must have screwed it up when I tested it. A value of 1 = SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS does the job! I'll update the answer.